# Cognos 10 list report gives different results on different PCs

Tags: report, cognos

I wonder if anyone can help. I've got a single Cognos 10 report server, with a number of list type reports. When these reports are run on different desktop PCs, I get different number of rows displayed.

For example - I have one list report that takes a single string parameter, and it uses that string as a like comparison on a column (essentially searching for a name). I get correct results returned (as do some of my colleagues), whilst others don't.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a minimal example ?

Comment: Hi - filter on list report

[Ad Hoc Reporting].[Applicants].[Applicant Name] like ('%'||?SearchTerm?||'%') 

Report has Applicant Name and address columns. Prompts for value. 

Say I enter "fred" at prompt - I get 3 results as expected, some of my colleagues don't.

Comment: Do you have data security defined in you model?

Comment: Hi. No, it doesn't. To check it's not variable by user, I've used my login on a user's PC that got the incorrect results. I also got the incorrect results on that PC, then going back and getting the right results back on mine.

Comment: Is there any difference in the language settings in the browsers being used?

Comment: Hi. I don't believe so - standard enterprise build for all PCs. But I will check. Thanks